# Select options from map function - ReacjJS

Tags: reactjs, html-select

Is anyone able to explain me why this code is not working?

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="input-field col s12">
    <select
      onChange={props.handleSelected}
      id="realEstateBroker"
      defaultValue={'Default'}
    >
      <option value="Default" disabled>
        Brak
      </option>
      {
        realEastateBroker &&
          realEastateBroker.map((broker, i) => (
            <option key={i} value={broker.firstName}>
              {broker.firstName}
            </option>
          ))
       }
     </select>
     <label>Opiekun oferty</label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Options from the map func are not generated on the page. On the chrome console I can see them under select but not in ul list (if I hardcode options, there are working). Working example:

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="input-field col s12">
    <select
      multiple
      onChange={props.handleSelectedMultiple}
      id="balcony"
      defaultValue={[]}
    >
      <option value="Default" disabled>
        Brak
      </option>
      <option value="Balkon">Balkon</option>
      <option value="Taras">Taras</option>
      <option value="Ogród">Ogród</option>
      <option value="Loggia">Loggia</option>
      <option value="Taras na dachu">Taras na dachu</option>
    </select>
    <label>Balkon</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

realEstateBroker is array of objects.

Comment: I've just tested your code with mocked `realEastateBroker` values and it works fine. Can you log `realEastateBroker` or give us some more information?

Comment: It's just an array of objects; object is looking like this:
0:
id: "LdROhGo0U1OHVID6gZhLx2AZekW2"
description: "Opis"
email: "o.test@gmail.com"
firstName: "test"
lastName: "test"

Answer (score 1):

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="input-field col s12">
    <select
      onChange={props.handleSelected}
      id="realEstateBroker"
      defaultValue={'Default'}
    >
      <option value="Default" disabled>
        Brak
      </option>
      {
        realEastateBroker &&
          realEastateBroker.map((broker, i) => {
            return(<option key={i} value={broker.firstName}>
              {broker.firstName}
            </option>
          )
         })
       }
     </select>
     <label>Opiekun oferty</label>
   </div>
 </div>
```

From map you need to return the values to be rendered on UI. Hope this helps!

Comment: realEastateBroker.map((broker, i) => () is the same as realEastateBroker.map((broker, i) => { return} so that's not it